mvn deploy with specified plugin version doesn't execute the previous lifecycle phase
At my company we are having a problem, we want to deploy a fat jar with shade onto our jfrog artifactory and we have just upgraded to Java 17, our ops team have defined the command that Jenkins uses to deploy the fat jar as
mvn jar:jar org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.1:deploy -DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository=central::https://artifactory.url/artifactory/libs-release -DaltSnapshotDeploymentRepository=snapshots::https://artifactory.url/artifactory/libs-snapshot --settings mvn_settings.xml --global-settings mvn_settings.xml

And when the .jar is deployed onto our artifactory it just has our compiled code, nothing about the dependencies as we expect with shade. Before it used version 2.8.1 and we asked to put the 3.1.1 to see if that was the problem.
On our local environment we can deploy successfully the fat jar to a directory with
mvn jar:jar deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshot-repo::default::file:C:\artifacts

and it works, shade is executed on the package phase like expected and we get a fat jar, but when we add the plugin like on the jenkins steps
mvn jar:jar org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.1:deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshot-repo::default::file:C:\artifacts

it doesn't, we just get a 4kb .jar with only .class inside
Our ops team doesn't want to change the command to just do deploy without specifying the plugin because according to them maven does weird things for older java versions (the same commands are used for all maven projects and versions), the easy solution would be to tell them to just use deploy but they need a good reason for that so that is why I am asking here (also does the jar:jar part do anything for the deploy?)
As a note, the problem just started appearing on Java 17, if we revert the Java 17 changes to Java 8 it works fine, and we can reproduce this on local with the same commands (with and without plugin version).

did you go from java 8 to 17 directly? Whats the last java version that worked?

@PerdiEstaquel we have tried with Java 11 with the java 8 code and works the same as with 8, but since we are going from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.2 we went from 8 to 17

@draconk On your local did you not try running the verbose(-v) version of the command to see if there is any error logged? use the same command to also see what is the deploy plugin version used when you don't specify 3.1.1 explicitly. i.e. with mvn jar:jar deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=snapshot-repo::default::file:C:\artifacts

Another aspect without which it's not straightforward to reproduce the issue or help is that the configuration within mvn_settings.xml is not yet known.

You seemed to misconfigured or not really understood the life cycle. It should be able to do mvn deploy instead of the whole commands... Also if you use spring boot the way via maven-shade is simply wrong ... use spring-boot-maven-plugin instead... there seemed to be a lot of misunderstanding how Maven etc. works and how it should be used...

@Naman -v on maven is for getting the version, I guess you meant -X for debug, the only difference is now I get Debug messages but I don't see anything pointing at the problem. On the mvn_settings.xml the only thing there is are the repository user and password

@draconk Yes, my bad, I meant -X for debugging. Have you compared the logs from a run with the version and without the version specified in the command line on your local where you are able to reproduce the behaviour?

@khmarbaise In this case this project doesn't use Spring Boot but a shared library between our projects and since updating other Spring Boot projects we just migrated all libraries to Java 17.

Even if you don't use SB ... usage of maven-shade-plugin doesn't make sense even more. Use a the usual way... just add the required dependencies to the project... also calling jar:jar does not make sense... better use the life cycle...If a shared lib uses SB ... than the consuming project have to use it as well.. Please make example project... If you use jar:jar you are calling a goal explicit but not starting the life cycle which looks wrong here... I don't understand why you are doing that?

@khmarbaise after a lot of back and forth with our ops team the reason for the jar:jar is that on a previous Jenkins step we already do a mvn install ... and jar:jar is supposed to grab the already present artifact to avoid having to rebuild everything as is explained in this other SO answer

If you already done an install the jar:jar superflous because the jar has already been packaged... If used an spring boot project the spring-boot-maven-plugin has already been ran so the jar file has already been packaged as well... so calling jar:jar sound really wrong here..also use deploy:deploy.. it's better to simply mvn deploy which will do everything in one go... without the hassle of so many command line options etc...
